# Android slider puzzle

Tags: android, puzzle, sliding

I am developing a slider puzzle in android one which has an image broken into small images and we need to order these pieces to form the correct image. I have used a grid view 3x3 which contains 8 images and one black spot. So basically when you touch on any of the 8 pieces the puzzle depending on whether its a valid move or not the piece moves to the blank spot. This all works fine but I want to give it the sliding effect. So when you touch the piece it should slide into the blank spot. I guess I have to use the onFling method but I am not very sure how.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you want to move image to blank spot ..right ?

Comment: Yes. and it does move as of now but i want to give it the sliding effect. Say when you touch on the image and drag it the image should move with the finger.

Comment: Actully i using slide but in time delay. i will post my code i think useful for you

Comment: my code is slide image on time so you only changes on time. you just call animation method on touch event

Answer (score 0):

this code is runnig on Time delay and slide image :-

```
public class SliderActivity extends Activity {

    public int currentimageindex=0;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask task;
    ImageView slidingimage;

    private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
            R.drawable.splash0, R.drawable.splash1, R.drawable.splash2,
            R.drawable.splash3
        };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mygame);
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();

            }
        };

        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

             mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

        }

        }, delay, period);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        finish();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
      }

    /**
     * Helper method to start the animation on the splash screen
     */
    private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

        currentimageindex++;

        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);

          slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a game engine for this. Value being that it handles the animation for you and animating a tile would be as simple as a single line of code ..

tile.MoveTo(newPosition).

I recommend cocos2d for android and you can find a detailed tutorial on building a slider puzzle here ..

http://denvycom.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-build-your-first-slider-puzzle-game-in-cocos2d-for-android-part-1/

The tutorial also covers building an image slider puzzle here ..
http://denvycom.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-build-your-first-slider-puzzle-game-in-cocos2d-for-android-part-3-2/#comment-1313951361